# RoutedEventArgs and AllFramesEventArgs

Tags: kinect, eventargs, routedeventargs

I am trying to call a function whose parameters are object sender and RoutedEventsArg e. I need those parameters since I have created a button on the main window related to this function and when I click the button it links to my function.

```
 protected void StartRecord(object sender,RoutedEventsArg e)
{
  // some stuff that creates a button and then does stuff
}
```

In another function, I need to call the above function stated above, but this second function has a parameter of AllFramesReadyArg e, not RoutedEventsArg e.  So how do i call out the first function

```
    void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
            this.StartRecord(sender, e);
        // does not work since parameter calls for RoutedEventArgs
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `StartRecord` is not part of the Kinect Toolbox.  You appear to have written it and given it those two arguments.  It doesn't need them, nor do you necessarily need the function.

You also do **not** want to be calling `StartRecord` in `AllFramesReady`.  The `AllFramesReady` callback is fired *every* time all the frames are ready for processing (hence the function name), which happens roughly 30 times a second.  You only need to tell it to record once.

Per your other question, `StartRecord` is a callback to a button -- it shouldn't be called in code.  It is called when the user hits the associated button.

Just looking at the Kinect Toolbox code and the callbacks, your code should look something like this:

```
KinectRecorder _recorder;
File _outStream;
bool _isRecording = false;

private void KinectSetup()
{
    // set up the Kinect here

    _recorder = new KinectRecorder(KinectRecordOptions.Skeleton, _outStream);

    // some other stuff to setup
}

private void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    SkeletonFrame skeleton;

    if (_isRecording && skeleton != null)
    {
        _recorder.Record(skeleton);
    }
}

public void StartRecord(object sender, RoutedEventsArg e)
{
    _isRecording = !_isRecording;
}
```

Comment: the _outStream has conflict as the parameter in the KinectRecorder function call, since it is looking for a System.IO.Stream variable type, but the variable _outStream is of type System.IO.File. And I had to initialize the skeleton to the most recent frame from the skeleton stream, by setting the variable skeleton = e.OpenSkeletonFrame().